# tSQLt tests failing with "could not find stored procedure 'tSQLt.NewTestClass' " error

Tags: sql, sql-server, visual-studio, t-sql, tsqlt

I'm trying to write the simplest test in tSQLt but i'm getting an error that i can't seem to fix.

This is my test.

```
EXEC tSQLt.NewTestClass @ClassName = 'LeadTimeTests';
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE LeadTimeTests.[test Assert equal data is equal]
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @actual DATETIME;
    SET @actual = '2004-06-30 23:59:59:998';

    DECLARE @expected DATETIME;
    SET @expected = '2004-06-30 23:59:59:998';
    EXEC tSQLt.AssertEquals @expected, @actual;
END;
GO
```

And i'm getting this error:

```
Could not find stored procedure 'tSQLt.NewTestClass'.
```

And in the Test Explorer window, the test is failing with the message:

```
failure.message: The test class "LeadTimeTests" or 
test name "test Assert equal data is equal" 
could not be found or does not have the tSQLt test schema extended property
```

I just can't find the fix to this.

Thanks in advance for any help provided.

Comment: Could you excute this `EXEC sp_configure'clr enabled'，1;  RECONFIGURE;` and what's the result?

Comment: It says "Configuration option 'clr enabled' changed from 1 to 1."

Answer (score 1):

You need to install the tSQLt scripts. See step 2

https://tsqlt.org/user-guide/quick-start/#InstallToDevDb

Answer (score 0):

Are the tests in a schema that has the tSQLt test class extended property?

You need to create a schema which is basically the test class:

```
CREATE SCHEMA [thingy_a_bob]
 go
 EXECUTE sp_addextendedproperty
 @name = N’tSQLt.TestClass’
, @value = 1
 , @level0type = N’SCHEMA’
, @level0name = N’thingy_a_bob’;
```

Please see this blog post: https://the.agilesql.club/2015/09/why-is-my-tsqlt-test-not-running/